# Getting certain file names using a powershell script in a folder

Tags: powershell, shell, automation, scripting

I'm brand new to powerscript, first time trying today. Familiar with bash scripting but this is different.
I have a folder of around 450 files. I need to get the names of about 30 of them, hopefully pushed out into a text file.

Here is what I have so far. I was able to get a text file with all of the files in it, but not one with just the numbers I feed in. I also noticed that lineNumbers.txt isn't created til the end, so i get an error saying it can't find it.

Please feel free to recommend references for fixes you make so I can learn.

```
$input = Read-Host -Prompt 'which file numbers do you need? Separate by commas' 

$input -split "(,)"

echo $input
Read-Host 

cd ./
dir -n > $file
(gc $file | select -Skip 1) | sc $file > lineNumbers.txt  
echo 'line numbers'

Read-Host

Foreach ($i in $input)

{

echo $i

(Get-Content -Path .\lineNumbers.txt -TotalCount $i)[-1] >> resultlines.txt
 

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a common pattern to those 30 file names you're trying to get, if so then I would harness `regex` via python

Comment: But before answering i would like to know what are the names of those 30 files. it'd be better if you can share the similarity that exists in those 30 files

Comment: Don't assign variable as `$input`. `$input` is an automatic variable in Powershell (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)

Comment: @mishx files are all picture names. 3 different prefixes (DSC, R000, L 000) followed by 4 different numbers in each one, also having the words final review at the end of each. also all jpg. would like to make this work on any set of random files though. 
Basically i'd have a layman go through and pick numerically number 4, 7, 8, when sorted by name, and then i'd just have to type in 4, 7, 8 and it would show me the names of those files in the text file. When using dir, the file returned comes back in this order. 
.

Comment: @itchydon thanks for the info, first script so I appreciate any corrections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter alternative:

```
$numbers = Read-Host -Prompt 'which file numbers do you need? Separate by commas'
$files = Get-ChildItem "Filepath" | Sort-Object -Property Name
$numbers.Split(",") | Foreach {$files[$_].Fullname >>resultlines.txt}
```

Comment: this is perfect. changing filepath to ./ because it's mean to be placed in the directory and it works. this will make things a lot easier, thanks. I'll have to look into get-childitem, sort-object, and the way you used the underscore in the for each.
One question. when it writes name, it writes the whole name of the file: Pc/mainfolder/folder/filename. is there a way to remove this first part and just have filename? 
Thanks for your help.